# VHDL timing question

Tags: vhdl

```
ENTITY top IS END top;

ARCHITECTURE example OF top IS
  SIGNAL w,x,y,z : integer := 0; -- initialised to 0 (zero)
BEGIN
  p1 : PROCESS(z)
    VARIABLE a : integer := 0; -- initialised to 0 (zero)
  BEGIN
      a := a + 20;
      w <= w + 10;
      x <= a + w AFTER 10 ns;
      y <= a - w AFTER 20 ns;
 END PROCESS;

 p2: PROCESS
 BEGIN
     z <= (x + y) AFTER 30 ns;

     WAIT ON x,y;
 END PROCESS;
END example;
```

question:why z rises to 40 at 50ns rather than 40ns?
If change z to  z <= x AFTER 30 ns; , why the first update of z takes place at 40ns ?

Comment: Please format and indent your code correctly. There is a code format option at the top of the editor.

Comment: sorry please have a look at this, I just editted another one  thttp://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215630/vhdl-timing-and-delay-question

Comment: @YichengYang Stop posting duplicates of the same question!

Comment: sorry I didn't know how to edit code format, I will delete my duplicates of same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you specified an **inertial** delay in the assignment of `z`. If you use a **transport** instead, then `z` will change after 40 ns. You get a transport delay with the keyword `transport`:

```
z <= TRANSPORT (x + y) AFTER 30 ns;
```

With an inertial delay, scheduled signal updates will be lost / overriden, if a new update is scheduled within the waiting time.

Comment: You can also get the same result as using transport delay by using a rejection limit of 0 *time_units* for inertial delay (the default delay model).  See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.2.1 paragraphs 5-7.  The rejection limit represents switching circuit delay, and if not specified is taken from the first waveform element delay.  A switching delay less than the rejection limit will not result in a signal transaction.

Answer (score 3):

You are specifying `WAIT ON x,y` in your bottom process coupled with `AFTER` on the assignment to `z`. These combined with your other process result in this delay.

---

I'm not a VHDL person (never used it), but from what I can tell from a very brief read of [this](http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00081.htm), [this](http://www.pldworld.com/_hdl/1/www.ireste.fr/fdl/vcl/lesd/les_4.htm) and [this](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/process.html) which give explanations of the VHDL `wait` and `after` and `process` statements respectively, the following will happen.

At t=0:

1. `z` is calculated as `x+y` which at the beginning is 0+0=0. **But** this value is not yet assigned (because of the `AFTER` statement). It will be assigned at t=now+30ns.
2. `a` is set to 20 using a *blocking* assignment which means within that process it is calculated before `w`,`x`, or `y`.
3. Next `w` is set to 10. **But** at the same time the next value for `x` and `y` are calculated (but not yet assigned). These are based on the old value of `w` and the new value of `a`. As a result the calculate values are `x` will be 20+0=20 and `y` will be 20-0=20.
4. The top process suspends calculations now until `z` changes.
5. The bottom process suspends calculations now until `x` and `y` change.

At t=10ns

1. The value of `x` is now updated to what was calculated earlier (i.e. 20)
2. This triggers `z` to be calculated as `x+y`=20+0=20. But it doesn't assign the value yet. Instead it schedules it for t=now+30=40ns.

At t=20ns

1. The value of `y` is now updated to what was calculated earlier (i.e. 20)
2. `y` has just changed, which means the bottom process is again triggered. This means the value of `z` is calculated to be `x+y` which is 20+20=40. But this won't be assigned until t=now+30=50ns because of the `AFTER` statement.
3. Because a new value for `z` has just be calculated and scheduled for t=50ns, the value calculated at t=10ns which was scheduled to be applied at t-40ns is cancelled.

At t=30ns

1. The value of `z` calculated at the beginning is now assigned because the 30ns delay is up. So `z` is set to 0.
2. `z` has just been assigned a value which means the sensitivity list for the top process is now triggered.
3. The new values for `a`,`w`,`x`,`y` are calculated.

...

At t=50ns

1. `z` is assigned the value that was calculated at t=20ns. In other words only **now** does `z` become 40.

---

Basically the `AFTER` are causing the values to be calculated **Immediately**, but not be **assigned** for the specified delay. Also, if any previously calculated values have not yet been assigned before the next value is calculated, it is cancelled and never assigned.

`z` is calculated to be 40 at t=20ns, but because there is a delay of 30ns specified, the value is not updated to be that until t=20+30=50ns.

---

These sorts of delays are not for use in real synthesis, but used to simulate propagation delays to identify timing problems or race conditions. Unless you have specific reason to be using them (i.e. making a test bench), don't use them. This is not how HDL for synthesis is used - you should be using clock edge synchronisation instead.

Comment: The bottom process `p2` is resumed when one of the `x` **or** `y` signal changes.

Comment: @MartinZabel Thanks, as I say VHDL is not my preferred language. I've updated the answer. I presume then that at t=40ns that ```z``` will also update at 40ns, but will be 20 at that point (as it was triggered by x updating at 10ns). The OP didn't describe that, but I suppose I could put it through a simulator.

Comment: Just simulated it and no, ```z``` doesn't change at 40ns to 20. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Never mind, I see now, it's because the ```AFTER``` cancels any previously scheduled values that haven't yet been assigned. Corrected the answer.